# Angular js: how to use ngMousedown ngMouseup

Tags: javascript, class, angularjs

Is it possible to use ngMousedown for adding class to a div and ngMouseup for removing the class again?
At the moment I use **ng-mousedown="activateClass()"** , in activateClass() change **$scope.className="data-active"** and change it again with other function with ng-mouseup. And use ng-class to add the class "data-active"
I don't wanna use $scope.className and change it with function in controller, because this function is used for several divs and I don't want to add the class to all of the divs I have.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Normally controllers should not care about your DOM. What you are trying to do there seems more like suitable for a directive. I would implement a directive:

```
app.directive("highlight", function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.on('mouseup', function(event) {
      element.removeClass(attrs.highlight)
    })
    element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
      element.addClass(attrs.highlight)
    })
  }
})
```

and use it on a div like this

```
 <div highlight="active">
      my content is here
 </div>
```

where as *active* is the name of my css class.

Answer (score 4):

did you mean this:

```
<div ng-mousedown="upordown='down'" 
     ng-mouseup="upordown=''" 
     ng-class="upordown">content</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use ng-events with ng-class to achieve it:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="click me" ng-mousedown="className='data-active'" ng-mouseup="className=''">
<br>
<span class="base-class" ng-class="className">Sample Text</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use controller, you may just write **ng-mousedown="className='data-active'"** in your view