# Angular Checkbox List multiple select

Tags: css, angularjs, checkbox, multiple-select

I've got a checkbox list that I am able to select multiple items at once by using the shift key (click/check an item, shift click/check another item and all items in between are checked). I've got that working (Y)

[Checkbox list multi select w/ shift click working](http://codepen.io/edsinek/pen/ezJWGz?editors=1010)

What's next is to try to get the mouse to allow multiple selection via click and drag. You know how you can do this with a basic `<select multiple></select>` element?

[Your basic select multiple element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple)

I would like to be able to do something similar with my checkbox list. Here's my initial attempt, but for some reason, I can't get the ng-mousedown / ng-mouseup to get triggered.

[My attempt to get mouse click drag working for select multiple](http://codepen.io/edsinek/pen/yJeXeM?editors=1011)

Any ideas or pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

I believe I have something working [here](http://codepen.io/edsinek/pen/BzjZbp?editors=1010), but every once in a while, I get the not allowed cursor when trying to drag. Any ideas on the not allowed cursor?

Comment: you should take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158530/angular-js-how-to-use-ngmousedown-ngmouseup     if you want click and drag to work  I think you should try capturing mouse down on parent that is <ul> rather than on each <li> s

Comment: @Dheeraj, how would putting mouse down on <ul> work - how would I know which item was the start/end to know which items to check/uncheck?